# なでしこ (the football team)

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know the opinions of non-native speakers.

The female Japanese football team is named なでしこ which means pink. My impression of pink is a flower which is cute but tiny and ephemeral. Whereas the members of なでしこ look far from being tiny and ephemeral, if not extremely stout and robust.

What do you non-native speakers think about that? I am not talking about aesthetic merit or lack thereof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nadeshiko doesn't just mean the color "pink". It's the Japanese word for the flower called pink, or carnation. In the Western "language of flowers," the carnation implies boldness, i.e. courage, due to the vividness of its color, as well as love, purity, and beauty. Therefore in Japan, the type of carnation called *nadeshiko* has long been associated with both beautiful and strong women.

Comment: The language of flowers of Dianthus is boldness?! Thanks so much for the enlightenment. (Upvoting done.)